# Regular Surface Patches

Tags: differential-geometry

Which of the following are regular surface patches? Let $u,v\in \mathbb{R}$.

$(i)$ $σ(u, v)=(u, v, uv)$

$(ii)$ $σ(u, v)=(u, v^2, v^3)$

$(iii)$ $σ(u, v)=(u + u^2, v, v^2)$

I'm not sure how to show this. I think if $σ$ is smooth and $σ_u \timesσ_v$ is nowhere zero, then $σ$ is regular. Any hints are greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: No, these two conditions are insufficient.

Answer (score -1):

**Proposition.** Let $p \in S$ be a point of a regular surface S and let **$X$**:$U \subset \mathbb R^2 \to R^3$ ($U$ an open set of $\mathbb R^2$) be a map with $p\in S$ such that: (S1) **$X$** is differentiable; (S3) For each $q \in U$ **$X_u$**$\times$ **$X_v$** is nowhere zero and assume that **$X$** is one-to-one. Then **$ X^{-1} $** is continuous.
Basically this means that **$X$** is a regular paraetrization of S. So you only need to prove, for each case, (S1),(S3) and that **$\sigma$** is one-to-one.
 
I think that is all.

Comment: You got the logic wrong: The condition (S1), (S3) are necessary but not sufficient. The standard example (for curves) is the "figure 8" (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2067540/an-injective-immersion-that-is-not-a-topological-embedding)) which easily generalizes to maps  of surfaces into $R^3$.