# Continuity of the figure-eight map

Tags: differential-topology

Let $\beta(t) = (\sin 2t, \sin t) :(-\pi, \pi) \to \mathbb{R}^2$. This is an injective immersion and so its image $S$ is an immersed submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^2$ ([the figure-eight](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2067540/an-injective-immersion-that-is-not-a-topological-embedding)). Let $G(t) = (\sin 2t, \sin t) : \mathbb{R} \to S$ where $S$ is with the topology and smooth structure as the immersed submanifold. The formula is the same with $\beta$, but the domain and codomain are different from those of $\beta$.

Example 5.28 of "Introduction to smooth manifolds" by J. Lee states that the map $G$ is not continuous because $\beta^{-1} \circ G$ is not continuous at $t = \pi$. In my understanding, $(\beta^{-1} \circ G)(\pi) = 0$ and the preimages of narrow intervals containing $0$ don't contain $\pi$, so it is not continuous there.

However, directly in terms of the open sets in $S$, I couldn't find any open set in $S$ whose preimage by $G$ is not open in $\mathbb{R}$. There must be such open sets in $S$ because $G$ is not continuous. What such open sets are there?

Comment: My copy of Lee's "Introduction to Smooth Manfiolds" does not have an Example 5.28.  Presumably this example is only in the 2nd edition of the book, which came out in 2012.

Comment: @JimBelk Google books shows the example in the second edition [here](https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=xygVcKGPsNwC&pg=PA112&hl=ko&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwir8qPP68nSAhVDVrwKHa0nCJ8Q6AEIGDAA#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is that the open subsets of $S$ with its given submanifold topology are *not* the same as the open sets in the subspace topology. For example, the subset $\beta\big( (-\pi/2,\pi/2)\big)$ (which looks like a backward S) is open in $S$, because we define the topology of $S$ in such a way that $\beta$ is a homeomorphism onto $S$. But the preimage of this set under $G$ contains $\pi$ as an isolated point.

[In response to @JimBelk's comment: Yes, the OP is referring to the second edition. The corresponding example in the first edition is Example 7.2.]

Comment: What I missed was the isolated point $\pi$ in the preimage. Thank you.