# If the image of an injective immersion is a topological manifold, must it be an embedded smooth submanifold?

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

Suppose $M,N$ are smooth manifolds (Hausdorff, second-countable). Let $ F:M\to N $ be an injective smooth immersion.  Suppose that with the subspace topology inherited from $ N $, the image $ F(M) $ is a topological manifold (Hausdorff, second-countable).  Then is $ F(M) $ necessarily an embedded smooth submanifold of $ N $?

Comment: No, this is not true. See this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2067540/an-injective-immersion-that-is-not-a-topological-embedding/2181531.

Comment: @AlekosRobotis I know this result, but here I further supposed that the image is a topological manifold, while the example in your link is not.

Comment: The image in that case is a topological manifold. It is diffeomorphic to the domain.

Comment: @AlekosRobotis Are you saying that a **eight figure** in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the **subspace topology** of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is a topological manifold?

Comment: Ah I missed that stipulation. I see.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you allow your manifolds to have boundary, then no: consider $M=[0,1)$, $N=\mathbb{R}^2$, and let $F$ be an immersion whose image is a topological circle which has a non-smooth corner at $F(0)$ (with $F(t)$ approaching $F(0)$ as $t\to 1$).

If you do not allow boundaries, then yes, by [invariance of domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain).  Invariance of domain implies that any continuous bijection between topological manifolds without boundary is an open map and thus a homeomorphism.*   In particular, $F:M\to F(M)$ must be a homeomorphism so $F:M\to N$ is a smooth embedding.

*Note that if $f:X\to Y$ is a continuous bijection between (second-countable) nonempty topological manifolds then $X$ and $Y$ must have the same dimension, and so invariance of domain applies.  This follows from the fact that $\mathbb{R}^n$ does not embed in $\mathbb{R}^m$ if $n>m$, which is another consequence of invariance of domain (restrict such an embedding to an $m$-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and apply invariance of domain to get a contradiction).  This immediately implies that $\dim X\leq \dim Y$.  On the other hand, $f$ is an embedding when restricted to each compact subset of $X$, and the images of these compact subsets must have empty interior if $\dim X<\dim Y$.  Since $X$ is $\sigma$-compact this implies $f$ cannot be surjective by the Baire category theorem.

Comment: Thanks a lot, and the fact that continuous bijection between topological manifolds is actually a homeomorphism really amazed me.

Comment: A little relevant? [Are manifold subsets submanifolds?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3297573/are-manifold-subsets-submanifolds)